# Is there a Skype "meeting" web control?

Tags: skypedeveloper

I only see a "conversation" control.  Are there others?  I'd like to embed the meeting UI within a page.  I tried loading http://meet.lync.com/... in an iFrame but JavaScript within the page stops the render process.  I've seen hacks to circumvent this, but I can't go that route.

Answer (score 0):

The Skype Web SDK only has Conversation control. You can do P2P chat as well as group chat with it. But there is no meeting control within the Skype Web SDK.